# Best location for litter box?

Tags: toilet-training, cat-litter

We've had the cat's litter box in the laundry room for as long as I can remember. Recently someone mentioned this is a bad place because of the exposure to all the clean clothes.

What is the most sanitary place to put it?

Comment: Without knowing the layout of your home, I would suggest a spare room or in an area the cat spends some time in. I wouldn't put it in a place where he/she doesnt go or is not allowed to go. A bathroom would makes sense if space allows.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as "the best place for..." for anything. Almost. There will always be advantages and disadvantages to almost any choice, about anything. Which is the best car? Which is the best house? Which is the best place to find a friend?

You say that the laundry room worked for you and for your cat for a long time. Someone pointed out a risk - that some of the "dirt" might come close to the clean clothes. You can add a cover to the litter box - many litter boxes come with that cover - even with doors for the cover. Additionally, you can build something like a house around the litter box, in the laundry room - to additionally contain the "dirt" particles from spreading out too much.

If you really want to change the location, then you need to analyze your house, to find another location which is convenient for both of you and your cat. And there you will also have the same problem: some "dirt" particles will escape the box and "contaminate" the room and its contents (living room, storage room, kitchen, hallway...).

---

On the other hand, you "contaminate" the environment also, as a human, when you use the bathroom. And the towels in the bathroom. And the clothes you wear. At one point, you need to draw the line between avoiding risks and mental affliction. Just use your common sense, and do what comes out of that.